# IntelliJ IDEA can't Debug because "transport library not found: dt_socket"

Tags: intellij-idea

I change my jdk a few days ago, today I changed it back. then I find my IDEA can run but can't debug. Here are Console info:

> D:\Java\64位JDK\bin\java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:59301,suspend=y
>   FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError= AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_LOAD(196)
>   ERROR: transport library not found: dt_socket
>   ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_LOAD(509)
>   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_LOAD(196): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]

I guess the first line is command that IDEA used, but I find dt_spcket.dll in `D:\Java\64位JDK\jre\bin` (64位JDK means 64-bit ) not `\Java\64位JDK\bin` . I don't know am I right and how to correct the path or solve the problem?

Comment: Does it help if you reinstall JDK into the new path which is ascii-only? Also check there is no other JDK in PATH.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with @CrazyCoder 's help , out-of-ascii path isn't the reason.When I delete the system environment variable , i find "java" command is legal in cmd, so i think there is an other java environment in my computer. Use `java -verbose` i find the location and delete it then problem have solved. So if you meet the same problem, check the environment first.if not work , try to reinstall the jdk :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was the diffents Java versions in the App configuration[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzj1W.png) and the project structure[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUdyO.png), I solved the problem by simply changing to be same.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).